# c++ getline function and background processes

Tags: c++, linux, shell, process, getline

Im implementing a UNIX/LINUX shell and im using `cin.getline(..,"/n");` to get the input.

Problem: background processes output on the same line as the prompt making `getline` take that output thus giving me “segmentation” failure as i parse the command later on.

Question: how do I make `getline` wait for an input from the keyboard and not the output of the child’s?

Example:

```
prompt~: (wait for user input here) ls &

prompt~: (instead of waiting for user input.. ls outputs here since its a background process making get line take that output) 

Segmentation fault

Application exits
```

Comment: why is the background process trying to read the same line?

Comment: The parent is, not the child(background process). Its a shell its supposed to read again.